# Symbol not found: _SSLv2_client_method

Tags: macos, apache, ssl, openssl

I was trying to update openssl so that it could use libssl.1.0.0 instead of libssl.0.9.8.dylib

So I moved the two files

- /usr/lib/libssl.0.9.8.dylib
- /usr/lib/libssl.0.9.7.dylib

into my home and I copied `libssl.1.0.0.dylib` inside `/usr/lib`. That didn't worked too so I re-moved the two original files to their location but now Apache (and other app using ssl) don't start anymore. Apache says:

> ***Syntax error on line 111 of /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf: Cannot load /Applications/MAMP/Library/modules/mod_ssl.so into server: dlopen(/Applications/MAMP/Library/modules/mod_ssl.so, 10): Symbol not found: _SSLv2_client_method\n  Referenced from: /Applications/MAMP/Library/modules/mod_ssl.so\n  Expected in: /usr/lib/libssl.0.9.8.dylib\n in /Applications/MAMP/Library/modules/mod_ssl.so`***

and `libssl.0.9.8.dylib` is present inside `usr/lib` so I don't know why/what it does not find. Is it possibile to fix?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apache 2.4.1 undefined reference to \`SSLv2\_client\_method'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9856812/apache-2-4-1-undefined-reference-to-sslv2-client-method). You need to configure with `no-ssl2` and `no-ssl3` so Apache does not try to link to it.

Comment: ***"I was trying to update openssl so that it could use libssl.1.0.0 instead of libssl.0.9.8.dylib..."*** - you can't because they are ***not*** binary compatible. Typically, you use some like [Macports](https://www.macports.org/), [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) or [Fink](http://www.finkproject.org/) to get modern OpenSSL, modern Apache, modern Git, modern cURL, etc. Or, you build new versions of everything manually.