# How to make a clean installation of OpenSSL

Tags: macos, openssl, installation

I'm afraid I have made a mess with the version (0.9.8zg) of OpenSSL which was installed on my Mac. While I was trying to update it, now I have some error and for some reasons applications like Apache or Google Drive do not work anymore and they don't even start.

I would like to know which would be the best way to restore openssl to a working version without re-installing the whole operating system.

How can I do that? 
Up to know I have tried to download `openssl-0.9.8zg` and build it with `./config`, `make` and `make install` but it did not solve the problem.
Please help me if possibile

Some command outputs:

```
$ file /usr/lib/libssl.0.9.8.dylib` --> `/usr/lib/libssl.0.9.8.dylib: Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64`
$ otool -L /usr/lib/libssl.0.9.8.dylib`--> `/usr/lib/libssl.0.9.8.dylib:
/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2d_1/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1213.0.0)`
```

The output of `nm /usr/lib/libssl.0.9.8.dylib` is [here](http://pastebin.com/a6yJegcv).

Comment: What did you do when you messed up openssl in the first place? How did you do that?

Comment: @EtanReisner thank you for you kind answer. You can read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34532646/macos-x-el-cpitan-symbol-not-found-sslv2-client-method what I did :( I'm really an idiot...if you can help!!

Comment: If you just moved those two files and moved them back then that *should* have fixed things I think. (Unless the files lost permissions/security markings/etc. that OS X cares about.) I would expect that there's an OS X restore tool that might be able to repair this for you but I don't know what it might be.

Comment: Yes, I just moved them back but now I have that error...

Comment: Show the output from `file /usr/lib/libssl.0.9.8.dylib`, `nm /usr/lib/libssl.0.9.8.dylib` and `otool -L /usr/lib/libssl.0.9.8.dylib`?

Comment: @EtanReisner: done, I have just added them in my question

Comment: It looks like you may have accidentally replaced the `libssl.0.9.8.dylib` file with the `libssl.1.0.0.dylib` file at some point. You'll need to find the correct original file.

Comment: @EtanReisner  It could be... but, how can I get (if possible) a new file `libssl.0.9.8.dylib`? because I don't think I will find it again... :(

Comment: I don't know. You'll need to look for a rescue installer, rescue tool, find it on the initial installation image, etc. Someone more familiar with OS X may be able to help more. I'd probably go ask about this on https://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Apple Stack Exchange](http://apple.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Also see [How can I reinstall Mac OS X (Lion) without erasing data?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/18730) on the Apple Stack Exchange.